# Find Largest in AnyType array

Tags: java, arrays, get

Hello I am writing this program, and I am trying to figure out how to compare two items in an array to find the largest item.

```
public static <T extends Comparable< ? super T>> T getLargest(T [] a, int low, int high){
    if(low>high)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    T[] arrCopy = (T[]) new Object[high-low]
    for(int i=low;i<high;i++){
        if(a[i]>a[i+1])
            arrCopy[i]=a[i];
        else
            arrCopy[i]=a[i+1];
    }
    return arrCopy[0];
}
```

But then I don't know how to test for it, I tried :

```
T[] a = {1,12,7,45,22,23,5};
    System.out.println("Array: [1,12,7,45,22,23,5] low=0 high, Largest?: " + rec.getLargest(a, 0, 6));
```

but I get an error message

> The method getLargest(T[], int, int) in the type Rec is not applicable for the arguments (int[], int, int)

How do I call it to make it an array of numbers? Would an array of strings work with the code I have for getting the largest?

Maybe is just simple answers but I've been working on the whole program for a while and things don't look so clear now.

**EDIT**

After changing the array from int[] to Integer[]. I am getting an error on this line `if(a[i]>a[i+1])`
 saying

> The operator > is undefined for the argument type(s) T, T

I'm assuming I would have to change the `>` sign to compare elements in the array, but how do I do this? Use compareTo() ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not working because `int` isn't a subclass of `Comparable` because it's not even an `Object`. Basically, you can't use primitives (`int`, `short`, `long`, `char`, `boolean`, `byte`) with generics.

Try calling it with an array of `Integer`.

```
Integer[] a = {1,12,7,45,22,23,5};
System.out.println("Array: [1,12,7,45,22,23,5] low=0 high, Largest?: " + rec.getLargest(a, 0, 6))
```

If you want your method to be able to accept `int[]`, you'll need to have a separate function for each one you want to accept (`int getLargest(int[], int, int)`, `char getLargest(char[], int, int)`, etc.).

EDIT:

In response to your edit, you need to use `compareTo()`. `<` is only defined for primitives.

Comment: @fgualda87 - I answered it, but in generally each question on this site should be one question. If you have more questions, open a new one. You'll get answers faster that way (I assume no one else answered this because they thought I already had).